# xfce Taskbar does not load after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, xfce

I installed Xubuntu to replace Windows (or at least use it as main OS) since most of the games I play are on steam now anyway.

Since the Xorg drivers are not suited for gaming I Installed the Nvidia propriety drivers. The drivers are working fine, but the xfce Taskbar does not load. I receive this message (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnfa0.png) followed by a text based login which appears for 2 seconds when booting into Xubuntu before the UI loads. Is that normal when you have installed nvidia drivers?

Here is a comparison of how it looks with xorg drivers compared to nvidia drivers: 
[image]

I am using a GTX 560TI graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you would call it "fixing", but I just created a new Bar and deleted the others, kind of annoying work, but it worked.

Just screenshot your previous bars and then create a new one using the screenshot. Time for video games.